# Is it possible to use 2 mouse buttons for key map?

Tags: 3d-view

I'm very new to Blender and coming from a different software package it uses left mouse and middle mouse buttons together to zoom. Is it possible to assign both these mouse buttons to the 3D View (Global)/Zoom View key map?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can zoom in and out by using the scroll wheel as opposed to Ctrl + MMB.